# How to position a hyperlink beside the middle of a textbox?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a hyperlink vertically so it's to the middle of the height of a textbox but it's not working for me.

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLtXA/) example. I want to do this without using Javascript, works in IE6+, the two elements need to be in the same td column, without using hard coded pixels, and the hyperlink to be right next to the right edge of the textbox (like it's shown in the example, just move it upward to the middle of the yellow box).

Comment: @Abhijeet It's part of a form.

Comment: "The two elements need to be in the same td"... unless we're allowed to nest another table or import a large robust CSS framework (like the twitter bootstrapper) then you're making things hard.

Comment: @perfectionist Nesting another table is OK. I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

As long are the textarea and a elements are inline elements, they will share their base line. If you float the elements, you can set the line height of the a element to match the height of the textarea:

```
textarea { float :left; }
a { float: left; line-height: 6em; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/aLtXA/6/

Comment: @Tony_Henrich: Well, not easily. That value is based on the number of rows in the textarea, plus some for the padding, border and margin. You could use another table so that you can use vertical centering, but the behaviour of tables is hard to predict so I avoid them in layout.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you *are* willing to nest tables, this will work:

```
<table>
  <tr style="vertical-align:top">
    <td>  
      <table>
        <tr style="width: 500px;">
          <td>
            <textarea cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
          </td>
          <td style="background-color:yellow; vertical-align:middle">
            <a href="">Edit</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      second cell
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but I *hate* this level of nested hell.  It leads to madness and grey hair.

I hope someone will post a nicer answer.
Is it possible perhaps with the [twitter bootstrap?](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#grid-system)

Comment: "Will work" - in chrome.  I haven't tested multiple browsers, and def. not IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/aLtXA/16/

I put vertical-align:middle on the TEXTBOX and anchor. As well, I removed the vertical-align from the table cell.